# Angular 4 Enum doesn't update in list

Tags: angular, enums, ngfor

I have a field (item.state) in my list (*ngFor) that I load from API, treat in a method and display in the screen this way:

```
<div class="posts col-md-12" *ngFor="let item of objectives.results" (click)="openItem(modalObjective, item)">
        <div class="row">
            <h4 class="col-md-11">{{item.title}}</h4>
        </div>
        <div class="row">
            <span class="col-md-2">{{item.description}}</span>
            <span class="col-md-3">{{item.ownerPersonName}}</span>
            <span class="col-md-3">{{setStateEnum(item.state)}}</span>
            <div class="progress col-md-4">
                <span class="col-md-2">{{item.state}}%</span>
                <div class="progress-bar" role="progressbar" aria-valuenow="70" aria-valuemin="0" aria-valuemax="100" style="width:70%">
                    <span class="sr-only">70% Complete</span>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

When click in an item, I display a modal with the details of this item. In this modal, I can change the "state" of this item through a "select html component". It's ok, but, when I change the state and close the modal, this item has a state updated, but this time with a number. The property is not getting into the method "setStateEnum" again, this just show the value returned from API (an integer). How can I do to every time I update a state, the property pass into "setStateEnum" method again to show the string value?

setStateEnum method in TS:

```
rivate setStateEnum(state: any) {
    switch (state) {
        case 0:
            return "Waiting";
        case 1:
            return "Running";
        case 2:
            return "Finished";
        case 3:
            return "Approved";
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

I just needed to add a parseInt to my switch case and than it worked!! Like masterfloda said. The problem is: the property was passing through the method "setStateEnum" and going to "default", because the method was receiving a string from the update!

Like this:

```
private setStateEnum(state: any) {
    switch (parseInt(state)) {
        case 0:
            return "Waiting";
        case 1:
            return "Running";
        case 2:
            return "Finished";
        case 3:
            return "Approved";
        default:
            return state;
    }
}
```

Comment: Try changing it to a `public` method and see if that works

Comment: if public/private would be the problem, it would throw an error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My guess is that after you change `state`, it is a string, not an integer and that's why the switch goes to `default:`. And you don't get an error, because the method accepts `any` parameter type.

Try checking for `switch(parseInt(state)):`

Although the cleaner way would be passing an integer to the method and changing the parameter declaration to `state: number`, because then you will be informed about malformated input parameters.